# How to use CASE WHEN in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use group by for the table `NRW_MONTH_DATA`.

```
 SELECT  [OBJECT_ID]
      ,[YEAR_MONTH]
      ,[SELLING_AMOUNT] 
      ,[DEFAULT_SELLING_DATA]
      ,[LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT]
      ,[RGCB]
      ,[ICKZ]
      ,[YCKZ]
 FROM [dbo].[NRW_MONTH_DATA]
```

IF `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT` is `0` then group by `OBJECT_ID` and calculate the sum of `[RGCB]`,`[ICKZ]` and `[YCKZ]`

```
SELECT @SELLING_AMOUNT=(ISNULL(SUM(YCKZ),0)+ISNULL(SUM(RGCB),0)+ ISNULL(SUM(ICKZ),0))
    FROM [dbo].[NRW_MONTH_DATA] 
    WHERE OBJECT_ID=@OBJECT_ID 
    AND YEAR_MONTH >=@SELLING_CENSUS_START_YM 
    AND YEAR_MONTH <=@SELLING_CENSUS_END_YM
    GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
```

Now I want to add a condition that if `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT` is `1` , I need to

`SELECT @SELLING_AMOUNT=ISNULL(SUM(DEFAULT_SELLING_DATA),0)`

ELSE use original result to calculate the sum of the 3 columns.

I use `CASE WHEN` but is seems  that I could not use it in group by

```
SELECT @SELLING_AMOUNT=
        CASE LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT WHEN 1 THEN SELLING_AMOUNT
        ELSE (ISNULL(SUM(YCKZ),0)+ISNULL(SUM(RGCB),0)+ ISNULL(SUM(ICKZ),0))
        END
```

The error is like

> The column'dbo.NRW_MONTH_DATA.LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT' in the select list is invalid because the column is not included in the aggregate function or GROUP BY clause.

Thank you in advance.

I need the `group by` to calculate the sum of them. Each row has an `object_id` and a `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT` and other columns for one month, I want to use group to calculate the sum during month span.
It works well when I do not consider the `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Why are you using `GROUP BY` in a query that is assigning a value?  The result should be a single row.

Comment: What happened when you used it in your group by?

Comment: @DaleK  I have posted the error and I know why it happens,I just find a better sql to achieve my requirement.Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't get that error if your case expression is identical in both your select and group by.

Comment: @Dale K You mean I use `GROUP BY  OBJECT_ID,LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT`?Will it have the same result?

Comment: Its probably not going to provide you the results you want. But either do what Gordon has suggested, i.e. aggregate the condition, OR use your `case` *inside* your `sum`. As Gordon says, sample data and desired results would make things much clearer.

Comment: I think your question is not clear, finally you want group by which column and which conditions?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want `GROUP BY`.  So just use:

```
SELECT @SELLING_WATER = (COALESCE(SUM(YCKZ), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(RGCB), 0)+ COALESCE(SUM(ICKZ), 0))
FROM [dbo].[NRW_MONTH_DATA] 
WHERE OBJECT_ID=@OBJECT_ID AND
      YEAR_MONTH >= @SELLING_CENSUS_START_YM 
      YEAR_MONTH <= @SELLING_CENSUS_END_YM;
```

Now, the problem is that a column can change values on different rows.  So, what row does `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT` come from?  We could assume it is the same on all rows.  Or perhaps you want an aggregation function:

```
SELECT @SELLING_WATER = (CASE WHEN MAX(LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT) = 1
                              THEN MAX(CASE WHEN LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT = 1 THEN SELLING_AMOUNT END)
                              ELSE (COALESCE(SUM(YCKZ), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(RGCB), 0)+ COALESCE(SUM(ICKZ), 0))
                         END)
FROM [dbo].[NRW_MONTH_DATA] 
WHERE OBJECT_ID=@OBJECT_ID AND
      YEAR_MONTH >= @SELLING_CENSUS_START_YM 
      YEAR_MONTH <= @SELLING_CENSUS_END_YM;
```

Comment: I need the group for to caculate the sum of them.Each row has an `object_id` and a `LOCK_SELLING_AMOUNT` and other column for one month, I want to use group to calculate the sum during month span.